# Html Grid Using Ul li

Tags: html, css

I need a help. Plz see the attached image. I am trying to make grid using html ul li with any height. I am trying to put column one after another without any white space in between . But unfortunately 4th column is going bottom.  How to fix ?

[image]

```
      ul.brik{
    margin-left:-5px;
      }

      ul.brik li{
       display:inline-block;
        width:32.5%;
        margin-left:5px;
       vertical-align:top;
        }
```

Comment: Could you please include your code?

Comment: Include your code in a post and replicate the issue in a JSFiddle if possible.  We aren't psychic!

Comment: It is clearly visible that you are making the ul li layout horizontal. make it vertical.. it will work.

Comment: Hello, Here is my code

Comment: Code included. Plz check  James Donnelly,  Ennui

Comment: On a side note: since this is basically a specifications table, I think you could use a '<table>' element instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't mind ordering your columns vertically instead of horizontally, and you don't need this to work in older browsers:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: column wrap;
```

With possibly some other [flexbox properties](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) should get you that layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because each `ul` appears at the top of the line it is currently in. Once a line break is introduced, the next `ul` will appear where you see it.

To solve this, separate each column by a `div`, and put the `ul`s inside.

You'll need to set the display of the `div`s to `inline-block` for them to stack horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not quite sure what it is you're looking for. it looks like you separate them with more divs, also i think for your purposes you can add a

```
min-height:50px;
max-height:250px
overflow:hidden; 
/* you could also try*/
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:20px;
```